# painting in c# with gaps

Tags: c#, events, paint

i'm trying to do a little paint program in c#. so far everything works fine, only thing is that when i move the mouse fast enough, gaps appear where there should be a solid line. i have tried everything from double buffering to decreasing the interval of the mouse_move event (i actually didn't find any method to do this, i think it would also be bad for other processes on the system^^)

could you point me in the right direction here? i tried overriding the paint method of the panel, but when i try this nothing seems to happen.

here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Paint
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        bool paint;
        SolidBrush color;
        //size of brush
        int pinselGröße;
        List<Point> pointListe;

        public Form1 ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            pointListe = new List<Point>();
            paint = false;
            color = new SolidBrush ( Color.Black );
            //get brush size from combobox 
            pinselGröße = Convert.ToInt32 ( nudBrushSize.Value );
        }

        private void btnExit_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            this.Close ();
        }

        private void btnClear_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            Graphics gfx = pnlCanvas.CreateGraphics ();
            gfx.Clear ( pnlCanvas.BackColor );
        }

        private void pnlCanvas_MouseDown ( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
        {
            paint = true;
            Graphics grfx = pnlCanvas.CreateGraphics ();
            //draw a rectangle with brush "color" and pinselGröße as the brush size
            grfx.FillRectangle ( color, e.X, e.Y, pinselGröße, pinselGröße );  
        }

        private void pnlCanvas_MouseMove ( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
        {
            if ( paint )
            {
                //Graphics grfx = pnlCanvas.CreateGraphics();  
                ////put old position of mouse into variable
                //int altePosX = e.X;
                //int altePosY = e.Y;
                ////grfx.FillEllipse ( color, e.X, e.Y, pinselGröße, pinselGröße );
                //grfx.FillRectangle(color, e.X, e.Y, pinselGröße, pinselGröße);
                //grfx.Dispose();
                pointListe.Add(e.Location);
                pnlCanvas.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private void pnlCanvas_Paint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            e.Graphics.DrawLines(new Pen(color), pointListe.ToArray());
        }

        private void pnlCanvas_MouseUp ( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
        {
            paint = false;
        }

        private void nudBrushSize_ValueChanged ( object sender, EventArgs e )

            //when value of combobox changes, read value into brush size variable
            pinselGröße = Convert.ToInt32 ( nudBrushSize.Value );
        }

        private void cmbColor_SelectedIndexChanged ( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {            
            int index = cmbColor.SelectedIndex;
            color.Dispose ();
            switch ( index )
            {
                case 0:
                    {
                        color = new SolidBrush ( Color.Black );
                        break;
                    }
                case 1:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine ( "Geht" );
                        color = new SolidBrush ( Color.Red );
                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    {
                        color = new SolidBrush ( Color.Blue );
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    {
                        color = new SolidBrush ( Color.Green );
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

when i do it this way:

```
private void pnlCanvas_MouseMove ( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
        {
            if ( paint )
            {
                Graphics grfx = pnlCanvas.CreateGraphics();
                ////put old position of mouse into variable
                int altePosX = e.X;
                int altePosY = e.Y;
                //grfx.FillEllipse ( color, e.X, e.Y, pinselGröße, pinselGröße );
                grfx.FillRectangle(color, e.X, e.Y, pinselGröße, pinselGröße);
                grfx.Dispose();
                //pointListe.Add(e.Location);
                //pnlCanvas.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        //private void pnlCanvas_Paint(PaintEventArgs e)
        //{
        //    Console.Write("mjsda2");
        //    e.Graphics.DrawLines(new Pen(color), pointListe.ToArray());
        //}
```

i get this:

[image]

Comment: Giving us a code written not in English you decrease amount of people who will try to help you.

Comment: ok sorry, i added a few comments for understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't sure which we were going for in drawing modes, so here is two versions:

Also worth noting, your paint event handler had the wrong signature, and thus might not have been hooked up to the pnlCanvas.

When doing paint code you should (almost) never need to call `CreateGraphics` - its usually a sign of "you're doing it wrong".

**This will let you draw lines by clicking points:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    SolidBrush color;
    List<Point> pointListe;
    Point _mousePoint;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pointListe = new List<Point>();
        color = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pointListe.Clear();
        pnlCanvas.Invalidate();
    }

    private void pnlCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        pointListe.Add(e.Location);
    }

    private void pnlCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _mousePoint = e.Location;
        pnlCanvas.Invalidate();
    }

    private void pnlCanvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (pointListe.Count > 1)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLines(new Pen(color), pointListe.ToArray());
        }

        if (pointListe.Any())
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(color), pointListe.Last(), _mousePoint);
        }
    }

}
```

**And this will draw one continuous line:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    SolidBrush color;
    List<List<Point>> _lines;
    Boolean _mouseDown;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _lines = new List<List<Point>>();
        color = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        _mouseDown = false;
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _lines.Clear();
        pnlCanvas.Invalidate();
    }

    private void pnlCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _mouseDown = true;
        _lines.Add(new List<Point>());
    }

    private void pnlCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_mouseDown)
        {
            _lines.Last().Add(e.Location);
            pnlCanvas.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void pnlCanvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _mouseDown = false;
    }

    private void pnlCanvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var lineSet in _lines)
        {
            if (lineSet.Count > 1)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLines(new Pen(color), lineSet .ToArray());
            }   
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: i dont know if im missing something here but this gives me also no output even though i added object sender to the sig of the pnlCanvas_Paint method. little note: i just added this one method manually, nothing else (maybe need a handler?) but i dont know if this is of any significance

Comment: +1 for the detailed answer. I can just add that if he wants to continue without drawing pixels instead of lines, he should draw on back Bitmap and then draw that bitmap on canvas in Paint event handler. Also your code can produce flickering if PaintBackground isn't overriden (depending on what is the canvas), so I'm suggesting to first draw on the bitmap and then draw bitmap on the canvas.

Comment: @user1589728 you need to set pnlCanvas.Paint+=new PaintEventHandler(pnlCanvas_Paint); in your code.

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick Yes there is a slight flicker to it, personally I would make my canvas as a `UserControl`, and have `DoubleBuffered` set to true.

Comment: @user1589728 See nick's reply for adding the handler, you an also do this from the `Properties` window in the designer - find the paint event, and use the drop down to select your (now correct) paint method (this is what I did to hook up your code.)

Comment: ok the second option works for me, but i still got one little problem. when i let go of the mouse and click somewhere else in the panel, a line is drawn from the point where MouseUp was called to the point where a new MouseDown is called. this gives me, in fact as you mentioned, one continous line even when i let go of the mouse button.

Comment: @user1589728: Disclaimer: no visual studio on this machine, so it might have some syntax errors now.  Hopefully this will let you draw multiple separate lines, with each line being stored as a list of points in `_lines`

Comment: beautiful, it works now. thank you very much, you saved me a lot of headache. i will try to implement UserControl and DoubleBuffered tomorrow, I'm done for today^^

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me where the gaps are occurring, but shouldn't you add your first point in the MouseDown event? Could that explain the type of gaps you are seeing?

And why are you filling a rectangle in the MouseDown event?

Otherwise, perhaps a screenshot of what these gaps looks like.

Comment: I think he is painting on the mouse down to support painting a single "dot" by clicking his canvas (down and up only, no drag).

Comment: but otherwise, yes it looks like forgeting to also record the mouse-down point in the list would cause a gap, with the initial "dot" followed by a small non-painted area, then followed by the line formed starting with the first mouse-move.  Good catch!

Comment: i add the points in the MouseMove method, but as i said, when i do it this way nothing is being drawn. only when i remove the override method and instead draw the lines in the MouseMove method, it gives me said gaps.

Comment: ok i have added a screenshot and a little explanation of what i did before. and i noticed that the pnlCanvas_Paint method is never called, i tried this with a simple console output. but it is never handled. :(

Answer (score 2):

Mousemove events are going to skip - mice can actually move quite fast, faster than the events and your app can keep up. As a result, you won't get a nice continuous stream of mousemoves, one for each pixel.

What you need to do is track the previous position you got in the previous mousemove, and then draw not a point but a line from the previous position to the current one. Unless the user's moving the mouse insanely fast, this will approximate the mouse moves well enough that you won't notice it's not tracking exactly every pixel.